# linux serial auto root login

Tags: linux

I am trying to STOP my linaro linux from automatically logging me into root when it boots up with a serial cable attached...

I have already tried manually stopping the service by addign a .override (which broke the whole root and I could not do anything)

can anyone point me in the right direction? I have a password set to the root user which obviously I never have to use because of this issue.

This system was installed and has always been like this since installation.

Comment: Look into where it starts getty services for the serial console. Usually auto-login is handled by getty.

Comment: @TomHunt I have tried this already :( this is what confuses me so much I cannot see anything that relations to an auto login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I have solved this issue!

in my version of linux (linaro)...

> cd /etc/init/auto-serial-console.conf

This file contains this line

```
exec /bin/auto-serial-console
```

then if you edit the above file you will find a big script but reading it carefully you will see it will lead you to this script:

```
/etc/default/autogetty
```

the script /etc/default/autogetty will then contain a line (or something similar)

```
AUTOGETTY_ARGS="-n -l /bin/auto-root-login"
```

change the above line to:

```
AUTOGETTY_ARGS="-n -l /bin/login"
```

This will now prompt you for a username and password when connecting via serial cable..